# VSTO - Calendar/Contacts/Tasks folder not show up in relevant Outlook sections after add

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

When i add a Calendar/Contacts/Tasks folder to Outlook.Stores programmatically, they don't always show up in Outlook relevant sections. Attached an example of the Calendar folders. All folders are created with the "Calendar" type, but one of them (sometimes several) are not transferred to Outlook sections for some unknown reason. Not show up folders in relevant sections shows in Outlook without dot on folder icon. After the restart, everything is displayed correctly both in folders and in sections. How can this be solved programmatically? This issue relates to all folders (Calendar/Contacts/Tasks).

[Sample of Calendar folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjFxn.png)

[Sample of Task folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8ot7.png)

Sample of the code

```
var testStore = Application.Session.Stores.Cast<Outlook.Store>().First();
var defaultFolder = testStore.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        defaultFolder.Folders.Add($"test cal {i}", Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Write(exception.ToString());
    }
}
```

[Result of the code executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqyE1.png)

Comment: As far as I remember, if I add these folders manually in Outlook, I will see the same behaviour.

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: So you see new folders in the nav pane if you switch to the folder treeview, but not if you switch to the Calendar or Contact views?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes, folder with dot on icon i can see in Calendar view, but without dot not. Only after restart Outlook folders without dot cahged to icon with dot and was added on Calendar view.
I was add code sample to reproduce my issue. Outlook version - 16.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Please view code example.

Comment: Is that an IMAP4 store?

Comment: This is an IMAP store.

Comment: IMAP behaves weirdly in Outlook. I don't think there is a workaround for IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

The [Folders.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders.add) method allows specifying the optional parameter which stands for the Outlook folder type for the new folder. If the folder type is not specified, the new folder will default to the same type as the folder in which it is created.

To refresh the explorer view you can set the `CurrentFolder` property of the `Explorer` class to any other folder and then try to set it back.

Comment: In my samples the folders was added with folder type parameter, but it doesn't helps. :(

Comment: What is your sample code?

Comment: I was attach code example, please view.

Comment: To refresh the explorer view you can set the `CurrentFolder` property of the `Explorer` class to any other folder and then try to set it back.

Comment: I was try to use CurrentFolder with code:

var folder = defaultFolder.Folders.Add($"test cal {i}", Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = folder;

But it doesn't helps.

Comment: Have you got any ideas?

Comment: To any other folder, for example, Inbox.

Comment: Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder = folder;

Doesn't helps :(

Comment: This is IMAP store issue?